# How to set the HTML of the first <li> element in the parent ul

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a simple JQuery AJAX update on a page, and I just want to update the first list element with the result thats returned from the server (its just a number).

My HTML is a bit like this (psuedo):

```
<ol>
<li>
    <ul class="product-controls">
    <li>101</li> <!-- I want to update this element -->
    <li><a name="PushUp">Push Up</a></li>
    <li><a>Push Down</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul class="product-controls">
    <li>5</li> <!-- I want to update this element -->
    <li><a name="PushUp">Push Up</a></li>
    <li><a>Push Down</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul class="product-controls">
    <li>33</li> <!-- I want to update this element -->
    <li><a name="PushUp">Push Up</a></li>
    <li><a>Push Down</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ol>
```

When a user clicks on `Push Up` or `Push Down`, I do an AJAX update to the server and it returns me a number. *The server knows which product to update (I excluded this code because its unnecessary for this example)* I want to update the first `li` with this number. I have tried this code but it seems to update the second `li`. That is, it updates the "`Push Up`" `li` with the number instead. I don't understand why?

```
$(this).parents("ul.product-controls li:first").html(result);
```

`result` is just the number sent back from the server.

Full JQuery code:

```
 $('a[name="PushUp"]').on('click', function(event) {
 $.ajax({
            context: this,
            type: "post",
            url: "page.cfm",
            data: $.param(data),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function() {
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $(this).parents("ul.product-controls li:first").html(result);
            },
            complete: function() {},
            error: function(a) {
                alert("An error has occured. Please try again.");
            }
        });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: Show your full jquery code.

Comment: As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/un9vw9f8/), your code works as-is. So your problem has to be somewhere else

Comment: here `$(this)` is anchor tag instance, right? Please share your ajax call also to get more clarity of problem.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar yes it is

Comment: Please share your ajax call also to get more clarity of problem. and check my answer.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I have updated to include complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this, get parent `ul` using `closest()` and find `li:first` to get first `li` inside `ul`.

**Note**:- assuming that `$(this)` is an instance of anchor tag.

```
$(this).closest("ul.product-controls").find("li:first").html(result);
```

modified ajax call -

```
$('a[name="PushUp"]').on('click', function(event) {

  var $this = $(this);

 $.ajax({
            context: $this,
            type: "post",
            url: "page.cfm",
            data: $.param(data),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function() {
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $this.closest("ul.product-controls").find("li:first").html(result);
            },
            complete: function() {},
            error: function(a) {
                alert("An error has occured. Please try again.");
            }
        });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `parents()` is not using the right selector, *li* is not the parent of *li*. You can use `parents('ul')` then find the first *li* or just

```
 $(this).parent().find('li:first-child').html(result);
```

Edited to match the scope

```
$('a[name="PushUp"]').on('click', function(event) {
   var $this = $(this);
   $.ajax({
     ... 
     success:function(result){
        $this.parent().find('li:first-child').html(result);
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: @Spookey thanks for this. it doesn't work for me however. i updated my question to include more code because I think its the $(this) part thats gone wrong!

Comment: @volumeone I have updated the answer, by the looks of it it was a scope problem because `$(this)` was not referring to the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Some how you can do this with `Class` or `ID`:

```
$(".product-controls").children().eq(0).html(result);
```

If you are using ajax `this` should be ajax request's object not hyperlink. You can check this by using `console.log(this)`, then you will find this refers to which DOM element

[**Sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/jxjh9yfo/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the :first-child selector

```
$("ul.product-controls li:first-child").html(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must get the parent, then go to the first li, it is a good way

```
$(this).parents('ul').find("li:first").html(result);
```

**Update:**

Here is a complete code: ;)

```
$('li.inner a').click(function(){
    var myUL=$(this).parent().parent();
    myUL.find("li:first").html("5");
});
```

OR

```
$('li.inner a').click(function(){
      $('ul.product-controls').find("li:first").html("for example: 5");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, closest is better than parent. You need first to find first ul with given class, and then look for a child inside of it:)

```
$(this).closest("ul.product-controls").find("li:first").html(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
        <ol>
        <li>
            <ul class="product-controls">
            <li>101</li> <!-- I want to update this element -->
            <li><a onclick="testFunction('up',this);">Push Up</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="testFunction('down',this);">Push Down</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ol>

        <script>
            function testFunction(passValue,curObj)
            {
                $(curObj).parent('li').parent('ul.product-controls').find("li:first").html(passValue);
            }
        </script>
```