# Can't seem to toggle an action after the DOM has been changed

Tags: jquery

Following on from an earlier question here [How to set the HTML of the first <li> element in the parent ul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382773/how-to-set-the-html-of-the-first-li-element-in-the-parent-ul/26382825) I'm having trouble getting JQuery to execute a function on an element after it has been changed in the DOM by JQuery.

So here's the HTML:

```
<ol>
<li>
    <ul class="product-controls">
    <li>101</li>
    <li><a name="PushUp">Push Up</a></li>
    <li><a>Push Down</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<!--- Underneath is what the HTML looks like when an Push Up has been made --->
<li>
    <ul class="product-controls">
    <li>5</li>
    <li><a name="PushRemove">Remove Push</a></li>
    <li><a>Push Down</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</li>
</ol>
```

When a user clicks on `Push Up` or `Push Down`, I do an AJAX update to the server and it returns me a number. *The server knows which product to update (I excluded this code because its unnecessary for this example)*

Once the action has been taken I replace the HTML of the Push button so that a user can remove the push. Like this:

```
$('a[name="PushUp"]').on('click', function(event) {
   var $this = $(this);
   var ProductID = // assume this is done;
   $.ajax({
   ....
        success: function(result) {
             $this.closest("li").html('<a name="PushNone" id="Product'+ProductID+'">Retract Push</a>');
            }
            });
                event.preventDefault();
    });
```

My next bit of code will not pick up on the anchor with a name of PushNone AFTER JQuery has added it above.

```
$('a[name="PushNone"]').on('click', function(event) {
....
// similar Ajax calls as above but it just removes the Push vote from the database
});
```

However the above code does pick up on the PushNone anchor link if its already there on the page before JQuery DOM manipulation. So if the page already has a PushNone link on it when it first renders, then JQuery picks up on it fine. It just doesn't seem to see it after the PushUp code as run.

Is thjs some kind of propagation issue or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [delegate](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) event, e.g:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[name="PushNone"]', function(event) {
   //....    
});
```

Comment: Thanks @AWolff. Why would anyone ever want to not delegate an event? In which case, why has JQuery been implemented like this?